# UIViewController or UIView? Or even a better design solution?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, widget, dashboard

I have a problem of designing an app. That's why I like to discuss it with you guys.

This app should be like a dashboard. You have several small windows/widgets that are filled with different data (images, tables, etc...) It is possible to add more widgets or remove them. Drag and drop aren't allowed.

What I am not sure about is designing it in the right way.

I will create one WidgetViewController for the widgets. So everything is kept encapsulated.
Then I will put all views in one "parent" UIViewController to use it with UIPagecontrol.
Is this a common way to have multiple UIVIewControllers in one UIViewController at all? I am not sure if this works anyway.

Or just create a class inherited from UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a container viewcontroller with uipagecontrol and uiscrollview that holds  your widgets just like the weather app in ios.Depending on the different widgets you need to implement different viewcontrollers and add their views to scrollview.If you do not implement different view controller you might have difficulties handling your subviews since you need to control your views from a single view controller.